# CSS/JS Framework for small websites

Tags: framework, css, wordpress

I'm looking for a front-end development framework for creating my websites. I create personal/small-business sites and shops using Wordpress. I use underscores as my starting point to develop my own themes. (for those who are not familiar - a stripped-down WP theme with nice templates, reset/normalize, and some basic CSS). Bootstrap would be an obvious choice, but it's large, 'bloated' and probably would be overkill. Googleing resulted in 30-40 frameworks that looked good. Don't have the patience/time to start trying.

Criteria:

- should be free/open-source

  should use SASS

  should allow me to easily manage every basic aspect of front-end development (navigation, headers, typography, grids, etc.) - preferably by predefined SASS variables.

  may include a js framework as well, but it's not a must. I'm fairly efficient at jQuery and I don't need tons of it.

Edit: After some digging I've managed to narrow down my options to these two:

- Groundwork CSS - looks nice, simple, has not been updated for a while

  Materialize - Material Design look, can be pro and con as well

Opinions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) the way you want and include only features you need to keep it lite.

Comment: I mark your answer accepted, because after quite some research for most people with this kind of problem, this would still be the most sound choice.
Edit: Especially since it's moving from LESS to SASS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Metro CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/) as a front-end webpage framework. It is an Open-Source and include JS framework.

Comment: Uses LESS instead of SASS (which is my preferred preprocessor)

Comment: @galingong Now I get to know about LESS and SASS, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent three days searching and testing frameworks, so I'm going to answer my own question.

The ones I've tested thoroughly were "MaterializeCSS", "GroundworkCSS" and "UIkit". I've also tried "SemanticUI" but passed since it doesn't officially have a SASS port. SemanticUI was the most advanced out of the four.

The remaining three are all really useful, but in the end I've found that Materialize was the one that allows me to work really fast and efficient. If you're into SASS, you can't go wrong with any of these though. UIkit also has a LESS port if that's a factor.